# PHPMailer erroring out with Call to undefined method PHPMailer::SetFrom()

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

Hay I'm using PHPMailer to send some simple emails, however the function SetFrom() doesn't seem to work, even though the code I'm using is straight from phpmails docs (http://phpmailer.worxware.com/index.php?pg=examplebmail)

Here my error

```
Call to undefined method PHPMailer::SetFrom()
```

and my script

```
require_once('inc/phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php');
$mail = new PHPMailer(); // defaults to using php "mail()"
$body = $message;
$mail->SetFrom('tell-a-friend@domain.com', 'tell a friend');
$mail->AddAddress($to_email, $to);
$mail->Subject = "tell a friend";
$mail->MsgHTML($body);
$mail->Send();
```

Any ideas?

EDIT

turns out the SetFrom() function doesnt exist in my version of phpmailer, i can set these values using

```
$mail->From = '';
$mail->FromName = '';
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Careful, there are multiple versions of PHPMailer around. I've never quite understood which is which. Anyway, [this download](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpmailer/files/phpmailer%20for%20php5_6/) of PHPMailer 5.1 definitely contains a `setFrom` method:

```
  public function SetFrom($address, $name = '',$auto=1) {
```

Comment: Turns out the function SetFrom() doesn't exists (as the error states) however i can set the variables $From and $FromName by using $mail->From = 'x';

Comment: @dotty you are probably using a different (older) Version of PHPMailer.

Answer (score 0):

I concur with Pekka; I downloaded PHPMailer from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpmailer/files/phpmailer%20for%20php5_6/PHPMailer%20v5.1/PHPMailer_v5.1.tar.gz/download), used your code as-is (well, I assigned the $to_email, $to and $message variables) and the submission was successful.

Try using the version Pekka suggested, or this one, and hopefully your problem will go away.