# Strange Fatal error: Call to undefined method PHPMailer::SetFrom() With Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpmailer

I am working on a Codeigniter project and added last version from phpmailer, and used this tutorial  to create a mailer_model

https://phpsblog.wordpress.com/2010/02/14/phpmailer-en-codeigniter/

After I adapted, I used it on another model and works perfect.

Now on this one I have this annoying error

[image]

Here is my custom library

```
<?php
if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class My_PHPMailer {
    public function My_PHPMailer()
    {
        require_once('PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php');
    }
}
?>
```

Here is the model with the issues

```
<?php
class Operators_model extends CI_Model {

    public function send_access($idpatient, $code) 
    {
        $this->load->model('Mailer_model');

        #Update code for access on patient Client
        $data = array('Code' => $code);
        $this->db->where('idpatients', $idpatient);
        $this->db->update('patients', $data);

        #Find Patient Email
        $qry = "SELECT Email FROM patients WHERE idpatients = '$idpatient'";
        $result = $this->db->query($qry)->result();
        $emailp =  $result[0]->Email;


        $subject = 'Access to Crossover Laboratory';
        $message = '<p>You now can access to our laboratory results with your name and code.</p>
        <p>Code: '. $code . ' </p>
        <p>' . base_url() . '</p>
        ';
        $body2 = "You now can access to our laboratory results with your name and code.\n
        Code: ". $code . " \n
        " . base_url() ;
        $body =
        '<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
        <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset='.strtolower(config_item('charset')).'" />
            <title>'.html_escape($subject).'</title>
            <style type="text/css">
                body {
                    font-family: Arial, Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
                    font-size: 16px;
                }
            </style>
        </head>
        <body>
        <p>'.$message.'</p>
        </body>
        </html>';

        $error = $this->Mailer_model->send_mail($subject, $body, $body2, $emailp, "") ;
        return $error;

    }
}

?>
```

I hope you can help me to solve this issue

**UPDATE**

Mailer_Model.php

```
<?php
class Mailer_model extends CI_Model {

    public function send_mail($subject, $body, $body2, $to, $attachment = "") 
    {
        $this->load->library('My_PHPMailer');
        $mail = new PHPMailer();
        $mail->IsSMTP(); // establecemos que utilizaremos SMTP
        $mail->SMTPAuth   = true; // habilitamos la autenticación SMTP
        $mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";  // establecemos el prefijo del protocolo seguro de comunicación con el servidor
        $mail->Host       = "smtp.gmail.com";      // establecemos GMail como nuestro servidor SMTP
        $mail->Port       = 465;                   // establecemos el puerto SMTP en el servidor de GMail
        $mail->Username   = "mygmail@gmail.com";  // la cuenta de correo GMail
        $mail->Password   = "mypasshere";            // password de la cuenta GMail
        $mail->SetFrom('laboratory@test.com', 'Crossover Laboratory');  //Quien envía el correo
        $mail->AddReplyTo('laboratory@test.com', 'Crossover Laboratory');  //A quien debe ir dirigida la respuesta
        $mail->Subject    = $subject;  //Asunto del mensaje
        $mail->Body      = $body;
        $mail->AltBody    = $body2;
        $destino = $to;
        $mail->AddAddress($destino);

        if ($attachment != "")
        {
            $mail->AddAttachment($attachment);      // añadimos archivos adjuntos si es necesario
        }

        $message = "Email Sent!";
        if(!$mail->Send()) {
            $message = "Error : " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
        } 

    }

}
?>
```

**UPDATE 01-09-2015**

Now I updated the phpmailer class, and changed the required class (see updated code above) for PHPMailerAutoload.php

The model on this question is working, but in the other one is not, and gives me this error

[image]

And this is the function with the issues inside Patients_model

```
public function Send_PDF($filename, $idreport)
    {
        #Send Email to client with php mailer library
        #Check config.php on config folder for credentials
        $this->load->library('email');
        $this->load->model('Mailer_model');

        $details = $this->ReportDetails($idreport);
        $patientDetails = $this->PatientDataById($details[0]['idpatients']);
        $to = $patientDetails[0]['Email'];
        $subject = 'Crossover Report';
        $message = 'Attached is the Report Requested';
        $body2 = $message;
        $body =
        '<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
        <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset='.strtolower(config_item('charset')).'" />
            <title>'.html_escape($subject).'</title>
            <style type="text/css">
                body {
                    font-family: Arial, Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
                    font-size: 16px;
                }
            </style>
        </head>
        <body>
        <p>'.$message.'</p>
        </body>
        </html>';
        $emailresp = $this->Mailer_model->send_mail($subject, $body, $body2, $to, $filename) ;
        return $emailresp;
    }
```

Comment: check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2509145/phpmailer-erroring-out-with-call-to-undefined-method-phpmailersetfrom)

Comment: @Saty thanks, already checked that a couple times some hours ago, I am using last libraries, and as I say on the question, it worls on a model, and on the one of the question doesn't

Comment: Have you call phpmailer library in your controller???

Comment: Show us the mailer_model.php

Comment: Try:
$mail->setFrom('laboratory@test.com', 'Crossover Laboratory');  //Quien envía el correo

Comment: @Tobias what do you mean? Is like that on the method

Comment: Possible the method is with a lower case 's': `$mail->setFrom([...])`?

Comment: @Tobias  still same issue

Comment: Yeah! Thats i mean. I remember not method in phpmailer start with uppercase letter. The same error?

Comment: Open file: `PHPMailer/class.phpmailer.php` and search "setFrom" or "SetFrom".

Comment: Not found  on PHPMailer/class.phpmailer.php

Comment: Than you need the newest version. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

Comment: PHP is not case-sensitive for function names, so don't worry about that. I can tell you are using an old version of PHPMailer so [get the latest](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer). It's not certain from what yu've posted that the loader is actually working. Consider using composer to load PHPMailer (and everythign else).

Comment: @Synchro now it gives this error  Fatal error: Class 'SMTP' not found in C:\wamp\www\Crossover\application\libraries\PHPMailer\class.phpmailer.php on line 1302

Comment: Yep, that's because you are not using the autoloader. Load 'PHPMailerAutoload.php' rather than `class.phpmailer.php`. It may help to base your code on a recent example too.

Comment: Ok now it works on the model with the issues and doesn't in the last workinh one it gives me this error msg Fatal error: Cannot redeclare PHPMailerAutoload() (previously declared in C:\wamp\www\Crossover\application\third_party\phpmailer\PHPMailerAutoload.php:24) in C:\wamp\www\Crossover\application\libraries\PHPMailer\PHPMailerAutoload.php on line 25

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I removed $this->load->library('email'); from the model because it was calling an old library, and it worked smoothly, thanks all for your help, your comments helped me a lot